# How to maintain similar look and feel of iOS app on older and newer iPhones

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sdk

I have been an iOS developers for a few years. But unfortunately have not developed any product from scratch, but mainly involved in feature implementation and bug fix hence was not able to convincingly answer few questions. Can you please answer the questions (or point me to relevant source) that I was asked during an interview?

1. How would you design your iOS app so that you make sure that they have similar look and feel in older iPhones (4S, 5 etc) and the newer iPhones (6S, 6S+) which have bigger screens?

   My answer was that we provide images of different resolution (higher resolution for the bigger devices) and name them as per the naming convention defined by apple. 
   He was not so convinced with my answer. 
   Are there other aspects than just images that need to be taken care of?
2. There are few functionality and controls and api's that are available in the latest iOS SDK but not in the older once. How would you enable/disable the supported feature in your code depending on the iOS version?

   Answer: I would define an macro containing iOS sdk version number check. I would use this macro to check if the current sdk supports this feature or functionality and then make the api call or add/hide the control.

   Are there other efficient and easier ways to achieve the same i mean by not using sdk version check?

Comment: Your answer to number 2 is wrong. Do not check the SDK version.

Comment: @maddy so what check do you do? OS version check?

Comment: Read the [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i)